# How to find an element in Cypress on a specific line

Tags: javascript, jquery, cypress

I'm looking for a way to use Cypress to identify the trash can icon, provided you have to select a line with specific text, in this case Cypress. The solution I tried is as follows:

```
var btndelete = cy.get('#SCGrouGrid').find('.dx-data-row').contains('UICypress').then("td").eq(5).find(".dx-icon-trash");
```

[image: Here is HTML of the web]
[image: Here is UI]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
cy.contains('td[role="gridcell"]', 'Cypress')
  .parent('tr.dx-data-row')
  .within(() => {
    cy.get('.dx-icon-trash').click()
  })
```

First, it will search for the `td` element where the text `Cypress` is. Then using parent, we go to the `tr` or row of the element where our text is. Them using `within` we are making sure the command we are running is scoped to that particular row only. Then we are clicking on the Trash icon inside within.

Comment: thank you Alapan, have you good webpage! Im newbie with Cypress and for me is useful. I think something is missing in your script, because I cant found the element. Maybe some class of td?

Comment: I have updated my answer